# VS 2008 - some parts of header not included?

Tags: c++, header, include

I'm working under Visual Studio 2008, maybe that's important.
In a larger project I decided to split one of my .cpp files into two. As I moved some of the functions to a new file, let's call it `new.cpp`, and tried to compile, I got errors that `new.cpp` doesn't know definitions of `fstreams`, `setw()`, etc. Now, at the very top of the new file I included my own header, let's call it `main_header.h`, which in turn includes all the necessary `<iostream>`, `<iomanip>`, etc. This works just fine all throughout older files used in this project, but for some reason doesn't in `new.cpp`.

If I add

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
// and all the rest
```

in `new.cpp` then all works just fine, but that's not how I want to solve it.
I thought maybe content of `main_header.h` doesn't get appended to `new.cpp` on compilation, but that's not true, I tried using in `new.cpp` an external variable declared in `main_header.h` and defined in yet different .cpp, and got no errors on compilation, linking, or running. Yet it seems like `<fstream>` and `<iomanip>` included in `main_header.h` do not make it to `new.cpp` file.

I'm relatively new to Visual Studio, so the solution to my problem is likely something silly I'm not aware of, but I spent a good while trying to figure this one out and to no avail. The new file is definitely part of the project, since building projects attempts to compile it, plus once I include `iostream` and `iomanip` in this `new.cpp` I can call its routines in other parts of the project. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

`main_header.h` looks like that

```
#ifndef MAIN_HEADER
#define MAIN_HEADER

#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
// loads of other stuff

#endif  // for MAIN_HEADER
```

Update: Ok, so the day after I created a whole new project using the same files and now all works fine, I don't need to include `iomanip` nor anything else in new.cpp. It sure as heck was to do with some oddities of VS not code itself, but still beats me what exactly was the issue.

Comment: Pay attention to magic stuff like "#include "stdafx.h", #pragma hdr stop" and similar that appear in every "working" .cpp file.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be the case, most of other .cpp also only contain #include "main_header.h" and work just fine.

Comment: Maybe you are missing `using namespace std;`?

Comment: No, I'm not. Really confused about this one :|

Comment: @sharptooth, @Eli - After some further fiddling around it seems this has to do specifically with `fstream` and `iomanip`. I tried calling function from `cmath` that was included in `main_header.h`, and that works just fine.

Comment: If the files arent too large post them. That should help. If you are using precompiled headers don't forget to include them in `new.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by prefix headers or precompiled headers, which can be set across the whole project, or could be set just on your `new.cpp` file, which might explain why there's some difference.  Here's a few things to try:

- Properties -> C++ -> Precompiled headers: check the setting for the whole project and for the individual files
- Properties -> C++ -> Advanced -> Force includes: check this is the same for both
- Open the vcproj file in a text editor and find the `new.cpp` node -- this is a quick way of finding if this individual file has different compiler settings
- Properties -> C++ -> Preprocessor -> Generate Preprocessed file:  this will generate an intermediate `new.i` file with all #includes and macros resolved.  Compare the result of this for both files and look for the diffs -- this might show why one works and the other doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Do you have another header somewhere that also has `#define MAIN_HEADER`?

It's an easy mistake to make when creating a new header by copying an old one, and leads to mysterious symptoms like this.